# Add p tag to unformatted text - Plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-manipulation

I have a content which inner elements text doesn’t wrap with any html tags. How can I add a “p” tag using plain JavaScript? jQuery solution is already existed but I need plain JavaScript solution. I’ve already tried with **“nodeType”**, **“innerText”**, **“textContent”** and **“innerHTML”**.

jQuery solution is

```
$('.arfaa').each(function() { 
$(this).contents().filter(function() {
return this.nodeType === 3;  
}).wrap('<p></p>');
});
```

How to figure this out by plain JavaScript?

```
<div class="content">

This is just a line of text.

<div><img src="demo.jpg" alt=""></div>

This is just a line of text.

<br><br>

<ul>
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
<li>List item 3</li>
</ul>

<br><br>

This is just a <a href="#">line</a> of text.

<br><br>    

This is just a <span>line of text</span>.

<br><br>

<figure><img src="demo.jpg" alt="text">
<figcaption>img description</figcaption>
</figure>

This is just a line of text.

<br><br>

This is just a line of text.

<table><tbody>
<tr><th>A</th><td>A value</td></tr>
<tr><th>B</th><td>B value</td></tr></tbody>
</table>

<br><br>

This is just a line of text.

</div>
```

**Expected output**

```
<div class="content">

<p>This is just a line of text.</p>

<div><img src="demo.jpg" alt=""></div>

<p>This is just a line of text.</p>

<br><br>

<ul>
<li>List item 1</li>
<li>List item 2</li>
<li>List item 3</li>
</ul>

<br><br>

<p>This is just a <a href="#">line</a> of text.</p>

<br><br>    

<p>This is just a <span>line of text</span>.</p>

<br><br>

<figure><img src="demo.jpg" alt="text">
<figcaption>img description</figcaption>
</figure>

<p>This is just a line of text.</p>

<br><br>

<p>This is just a line of text.</p>

<table><tbody>
<tr><th>A</th><td>A value</td></tr>
<tr><th>B</th><td>B value</td></tr></tbody>
</table>

<br><br>

<p>This is just a line of text.</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it in pure javascript. Use the findTextNodesFlat to replace the Each function. If you want to get all texts nodes (independent of its depth), use the findTextNodesTree instead. Then wrap the textnodes using the wrapTextNodes function.

```
// walks the child elements of a dom element and saves textnodes to the textNodes array
var findTextNodesFlat = function (node, textNodes) {
    node = node.firstChild;
    while(node) {
        if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
            textNodes.push(node);

        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};

// walks the dom element recursively and saves textnodes to the textNodes array
var findTextNodesTree = function (node, textNodes) {
    if (node.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE)
        textNodes.push(node);

    node = node.firstChild;
    while(node) {
        findTextNodes(node, textNodes);
        node = node.nextSibling;
    }
};

// wraps the textNodes elements with <p></p>
var wrapTextNodes = function (textNodes) {
    for(let node of textNodes) {
        let parentNode = node.parentNode;
        let wrapper = document.createElement('p');
        parentNode.insertBefore(wrapper, node);
        wrapper.appendChild(node);
    }
};

var textNodes = [];
findTextNodesFlat(document.getElementsByClassName("content")[0], textNodes);
wrapTextNodes(textNodes);
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer. But I expected to wrap the unwrapped text only. But this is also wrapping the text inside the element.

Comment: Modified the example to exactly mimic the each function with the findTextNodesFlat function. Renamed the findTextNodes to findTextNodesTree.

Comment: Appreciate your valuable time and reply. This is really interesting. In DOM empty “p” tags there. If I manipulate the empty tag by “.textContent.replace(/[\n\r]+|[\s]{2,}/g, ' ').trim().length === 0”, still something missing. “This is just a <a href="#">line</a> of text” manipulated into <p> This is just a</p> <a href="#">line</a> <p> of text </p>. Clean HTML should be <p> This is just a <a href="#">line</a> of text </p>.

Comment: I compared the result of the jquery solution with mine and they produce exactly the same result. So imho you probably should include this in your question.